# PHP Explode - A quick query

Tags: php, explode

I've got an array of data which is as follows :

> 'valid' => string 'true' (length=4)
>
> 'test_status' => string 'true' (length=4)
>
> 'trans_id' => string 'TRAN000102' (length=10)
>
> 'mpi_status_code' => string '200' (length=3)
>
> 'mpi_message' => string 'Payer Verification Required' (length=27)
>
> 'acs_url' => string
>   'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.secpay.com%2Fjava-bin%2FACSSimulator%3Fpartner%3Dsecpay%26VAA%3DB'
>   (length=83)
>
> 'MD' => string '1158465348' (length=10)
>
> 'PaReq' => string
>   'eJxVUmFvgjAQ/b5fQfwBtBQwao4apybzA+o2s++kXJQNChaY7N/vqjBdE5J7d/d6716BeVfkzjeaOit1NPJcPprLJzicDOLqHVVrUEKMdZ0c0clS6vDCSTAO/WAykrBfvOFZQk+XxHYFsAESz6hTohsJiTo/b7YyEFMuAmA9hALNZiVDPvYDEXr8doDd0qCTAmWusNQ594BdIaiy1Y35kRMxBjYAaE0uT01TzRi7XC7ujZRpdFXptl/AbB3YXc++tVFN93VZKuPD2tutXsX2EPPdcnHc3L8ImO2ANGlQCu7R4cLh05kXznxScM1DUlghkmqkvgdQ2RmLx8pjBshag1oNmwwIsKtKjdRBTv7FkGKt5JKGmUwfnfW5zaqCCiTAFoDdF1q+WLtVQw5+fK4F7dbFr1FkTb8m7YCMPPN8a2oPgFka69+T9Q9O0b8f4ReyL7Xp'
>   (length=452)

I'm using PHP Explode to seperate the arguements using the following code :

```
foreach ( $args as $arg) {
        list($key, $value) = explode("=", $arg);
        $result_arr[$key] = $value;
      }
```

Now my question is that sometimes when I send that PaReq code it comes back invalid. The people at the payment side have said that I am missing == from the end of the string.

When using explode("=") is that would could be causing the == to dissapear from the end of the string?

If so what would be the better way to seperate and read the array. Or does it not make a difference anyway?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What are you exploding exactly? If this is a `var_dump` of an array, please include it properly

Comment: I assume that there was originally an `==` on the end of PaReq? I don't see one there now...

Comment: Yeah according to the guys at paypoint when I get this error, its because I am missing the == from the end of the string, My example array does not contain this either.

Comment: Base64 doesn't **require** the `==` in every situation, it's simply used as padding when the data size doesn't fit a certain block size. However, I get data that doesn't look "normal" when I try to decode your base64: `x�URao�0...`, and adding the `==` makes no difference.

Comment: If you want to easily translate between base64, ASCII and hex, this site is my favourite tool for the job: http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/

Comment: @Polynomial the paReq code there, are you suggesting that I may need to decode then reencode the string?

Comment: @StuBlackett - No. I'm suggesting that your encoding format (separating with `=`) is not applicable for data that contains an `=` character. You should change it to a more robust format, e.g. JSON. If you've encoded a bunch of non-ASCII binary data, then there's nothing wrong with the base64 itself. Check that the data is correct using the tool I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exploding using a delimiter that is repeated in your data.

Here's what's happening:

`a=svyndf124iasvfABas==    ->    array('a', 'svyndf124iasvfABas', '', '')`

You could hack this by replacing '=' in your data with '!' or another placeholder, but the real trick would be to simply encode the list better. I'd suggest [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

However, it seems (as per your comments) that you have deeper problems than just your data encoding.

Comment: Its just that one, without the == which from what you guys are saying just adds to the string, if its too short